# play framework form issues

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

i am doing the example on http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList
but i have problem with the form.
If you look under the "The task form" section you will see that i am asked to add
static Form taskForm = form(Task.class);
to the Application controller.

The problem i am getting is "The method form(Class) is undefined for the type Application"

I am running play-2.1-RC1 instead of play-2.0.4 (play-2.0.4 is the one talked about in the example)

This is the compilation error  i got

```
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /Users/johnnybekkestad/Documents/workspace/play/todolist/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/johnnybekkestad/Documents/workspace/play/todolist/app/controllers/Application.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
[error]     static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);
[error]                                  ^
[error]   symbol:   method form(Class<Task>)
[error]   location: class Application
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -

! @6d1acongn - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: cannot find symbol]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:319) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

change line:

```
form(Task.class);
```

for:

```
Form.form(Task.class);
```

And of course you have to add:

```
import views.html.*;
```